# Why isn't my WPF binding working?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This seems so easy. I've been doing some much more completed data binding, and now I can't get this simple test to work. What am I doing wrong?

Disclaimer: It is late on Friday after a long week.

Here is my XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="MainWindowControl"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowControl, Path=Test, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code-behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string _test = "testing 1..2..3";
        public string Test { get { return _test; } set { _test = value; } }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the debug output that shows it is working fine. But it doesn't!

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=24898218) for Binding (hash=15584387)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'Test'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.DataContext (hash=61116530)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 :     Lookup name MainWindowControl:  queried TextBlock (hash=61116530)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): Activate with root item MainWindow (hash=22749765)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218):   At level 0 - for MainWindow.Test found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Test)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): Replace item at level 0 with MainWindow (hash=22749765), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Test)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): GetValue at level 0 from MainWindow (hash=22749765) using RuntimePropertyInfo(Test): 'testing 1..2..3'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): TransferValue - got raw value 'testing 1..2..3'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=24898218): TransferValue - using final value 'testing 1..2..3'
```

Comment: Just looking at your code, it looks like your path should be DataContext.Test instead of just "Test". You also aren't setting the DataContext of the main window, so I'm kind of surprised you are getting as far as the debug window indicates. Of course, this whole design isn't very MVVM-friendly, and I would change it to fit that model a bit better. You are also setting "DataContext" for the TextBlock instead of "Text". Perhaps you should try binding/setting that property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bound your string property to the `DataContext` of your `TextBlock`. It's working as it should. I can only guess, but did you mean to bind to the `Text` property of `TextBlock` so you can see the text appear?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowControl, Path=Test" />
```

Comment: *:-|    I knew I was being a bone head. Thanks for the help nvoigt.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the datacontext into codebehind.

```
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication1
 {
    /// <summary>    
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml    
    /// </summary>

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string _test = "testing 1..2..3";    
        public string Test { get { return _test; } set { _test = value; } }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded+=(s,a)=>
             {
                this.DataContext=Test;
             };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. You don't want to set the the windows's data context to a `string` object.